# Help me solve the examples

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have some examples, but I can not you choose, please help me:

$1)$ If $a-\frac{1}{a}=4,$ find $a^4+\frac{1}{a^4}$

$2)$ If $2a-\frac{1}{a}=5,$ find $2a^2-7a+\frac{1}{a}$

$3)$ Find $p\Leftrightarrow r$ if $p\Rightarrow(q\Rightarrow r)\equiv 0$

Thanky very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $1)$

First we find: $a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}.$ For this purpose we start from

$\left(a-\frac{1}{a}\right)^2=a^2-2+\frac{1}{a^2}=a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}-2$

$18=a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}.$ Now we have:

$\left(a-\frac{1}{a} \right)^4=4^4$

$a^4-4\cdot a^3\cdot\frac{1}{a}+6\cdot a^2\cdot\frac{1}{a^2}-4\cdot a\cdot\frac{1}{a^3}-\frac{1}{a^4}=256$

$a^4-4a^2+6-\frac{4}{a^2}+\frac{1}{a^4}=256$

$a^4+\frac{1}{a^4}-4\left(a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}\right)+6=256$

$a^4+\frac{1}{a^4}-4\cdot 18+6=256$

$a^4+\frac{1}{a^4}=322$

For $2)$ we have:

$2a-\frac{1}{a}=5\Rightarrow 2a^2-5a=1$

$2a^2-7a+\frac{1}{a}=2a^2-5a-2a+\frac{1}{a}=1-2a+\frac{1}{a}=1-\left(2a-\frac{1}{a}\right)1-5=-4$

Comment: Make it simple by using $$(a^2+\frac {1}{a^2})^2=a^4+\frac{1}{a^4}+2$$

Comment: Yes. But, full ways may be found, it's what the above methods no errors